# Mock a particular method in DAO layer in junit

Tags: junit, mockito, junit4, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have an application with rest api endpoints. I want to write test cases for that. It follows MVC architecture. For one of the end points I want to mock a method in my DAO class.

Sample code for my test class is:

```
RequestBuilder requestGetBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get("/processcal/getdata/srn/{srn}",1000)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

This controller will call the DAO layer having that method to be mocked.
I tried using the mockito as below in my Test config class:

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    BookMarkDao bookMarkDao() {
        final BookMarkDao bookMarkDao = Mockito.mock(BookMarkDao.class);
        Mockito.when(bookMarkDao.fetchMrPostProcessCalc(Mockito.anyString()))
                .thenReturn(TestUtils.getMockResponse());
        return bookMarkDao;
    }
```

The problem with this is it's mocking the entire DAO bean so for rest of the endpoints its not calling the DAO class methods and my test coverage reduces. Is there a way around solving this?

Comment: I don't think the coverage of your controller class should have any dependency on the DAO class invocation as unit tests are testing only the piece of code that is present in the class.

Comment: Can you share your test class file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a specific profile for mocked beans and activate this profile in necessary test cases. By the way, if your application based on the spring-boot then you can use @MockBean instead of manual making a mock of your DAO in test configurations.